# Why does defaultValue not display anything inside a text field when using an API call (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, textfield

This is the code I have, but it's not displaying properly

```
<TextField
                size="small"
                className="typing-container"
                defaultValue={thing.thingLastName}
                label="Last Name"
                onChange={(event) => setFirst(event.target.value)}
                required
              />
```

when I change defaultValue to value, it displays but then you can't edit the field at all. This all displays properly when used earlier inside a h5 tag

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to store the `value` in local state. Something like:

```
const MyComp => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue)

  return (
    <TextField
      ...
      onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
      value={value}
    />
  )
}
```

then whenever your `onChange` event fires, it updates the `value` and passes it into the `TextField`. We don't need to use the `defaultValue` prop anymore because the `useState` hook takes a default value and sets that as the initial value for `value`

Comment: Would I then be able to actually edit the value"?

Comment: @Filotimo yes, the onChange handler is what allows the value to be changed

Comment: Does it require the local variable for that? Also, would that require all of the different props? Currently if I have
`<TextField

                size="small"

                className="typing-container"

                value={thing.thingLastName}

                label="Last Name"

                onChange={(event) => setFirst(event.target.value)}

                required
              />`

I still can't edit

Comment: It requires a state variable, but it doesn't necessarily need to be local to this particular component. Without storing the value in state, there's no way to change the value. The other props are unrelated to this, so they are not needed for the functionality. It's up to you to decide the values of those props based on the needs of your application

Answer (score 0):

Try pass a state to value property, set the state to the default value that you want, later change the value using the onChange property.

```
function Comp () {
    const {value, setValue} = useState('Default Value')
return (
<TextField
 value={value}

 onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
 required
 />

)
}
```